# Modify preseed file to automatically install packages in /pool/extra

Tags: ubuntu

I want to modify the preseed file of an unpacked (using UCK) GNU/Linux ISO, and then re pack it (using UCK).

What I am trying to do is, modify the preseed file in such a manner that what all packages in .deb format I copy to the `pool/extras` folder, they get installed automatically during the OS installation. 
For that I will need to add something in the preseed file. I have not been able to figure out what it is. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you create a metapackage which depends on all the packages you want installed, and simply set up the preseed to install that.

[`equivs`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/equivs) was designed for this sort of thing, although it's not very hard to create a metapackage from scratch with the standard packaging tools, either.

To instruct the installer to install packages, you can include the line

```
d-i pkgsel/include string package1 package2
```

in your preseed file. If you just want to install all the `*.deb` files from a directory (not a full Apt repository with `Packages.gz` etc) then maybe

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target dpkg -i /pool/extras/*.deb
```

but I would actually prefer a full repo; basically it just takes a run of `dpkg-scanpackages`.

Comment: Ok that will work as well, but how do I ask the preseed file to install that as well. I don't know anything about modifying preseed file. I have read the tutorials, on the ubuntu's official website, but they have just confused me even more.

Comment: Updated answer slightly; hope this helps.